# Maximum number of elements in the subset.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, contest-math

> If $A=[91,92,93,…,180]$ and $B$ is a subset of $A$ such that the sum
> of no two elements of $B$ is a multiple of $9$, then what can be the
> maximum number of elements in $B$?

I am not able to find a  away to solve this problem. Let's say I take to keep $91$ in the subset then I can't have $98,107,116,125,134,143,152,161,170$ and $179$ but how can I generalize this thing for this problem?

Comment: Work $\pmod 9$.  The answer I get is $41$.

Comment: @RobertShore : your answer is correct. Can you please show me how you solved this? That will be really helpful.

Comment: I'm reluctant to do so because I'm not seeing evidence of what you've tried and where you're stuck in your efforts to reach a solution.  Please **edit your question** to show this information.  What simple property do $98, 107, 116, 125, 134, 143, 152, 161, 170, 179$ have in common?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's simple!

Consider the numbers modulo 9, then we can see:

1. There can't be more than one number divisible by 9
2. If we choose $a \equiv i$ (mod $9$) then we cannot choose $b \equiv 9-i$ (mod $9$), $\forall 1 \le i \le 9$.

Then, among $10$ numbers that are divisible by 9, there can be at most one selected.

Among $80$ others, there can be at most $40$ selected. (if you cannot imagine, try pairing the numbers, even though that might not be the best way to interpret this)

This yields the final answer of $40+1=41$